# Font Face Weight Render Issue

Tags: wordpress, css, font-face

I'm in the process of migrating a website from an existing CMS over to WordPress. They use font-face for their primary type on the site. I've copied over the font files and replicated the CSS file but it appears that the font on the dev site is not rendering the same that it did on the initial site (dev site has lighter weighted font).

Anyone have an idea why this may be?

Dev Site: http://gldev.staging.wpengine.com

Original Site: http://growingleaders.com

Comment: A question should contain enough code to demonstrate the problem. Links to live pages are not enough; the question becomes meaningless to future visitors as soon as the problem has been fixed or the pages have otherwise changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your dev site has a lighter font appearance because it uses

```
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

which makes fonts appear lighter. This is done quite often for exactly this purpose, though doing so is [somewhat problematic](http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/)

The rule is applied on line 19 of your compiled CSS file, applied to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences on the Dev page compared to the original. If you look at the CSS file called `screen.css` it is a quite different file on the two sites, that is one of the reasons the fonts differ. Furthermore there are 13 CSS files linked to the original page and 15 to the Dev page. Also the scripts differ, so I wouldn't be surprised if there are even bigger discrepancies than the font rendering.

Copying a WP site can sometimes be more tricky than just copying files. I would suggest you use a good migrating tool. There are some out there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Apparently having `text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;` in your code causes webkit to render the font thinner than FireFox. Once that was removed from the HTML & body CSS, the font renders the same weight cross-broswer.